# requirejs, is it possible to create a shim that loads deps after path

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Here is what I am trying to achieve.

I have a primary library that needs to be loaded with several other libraries that need to be loaded after the primary library.

All the secondary libraries require the primary library to be loaded.

Is there something like the reverse of shim deps?

primarylib.js
secondarylib1.js
secondarylib2.js
secondarylib3.js
secondarylib4.js
secondarylib5.js
....

i would like to call something like:

```
require(['primarylib'], function(){

})
```

primarylib.js should be loaded first and then all of the secondary libraries should be loaded.

If I use the normal shim method I need to set each secondary library to require the primary lib.
When I want to call the libs I need to call all of the secondary libraries in my require() call instead of a single lib which I would like to avoid at all costs.

---

**EDIT: Some additional comments and context**

---

I am trying to implement blueimp's file uploader.

It was crying about load-image dependancies.

The final config for the load-image files looks something like this.

```
        "load-image": {
            "path": "lib\/blueimp-load-image\/load-image"
        },
        "load-image-exif-map": {
            "path": "lib\/blueimp-load-image\/load-image-exif-map",
            "shim": {
                "deps": [
                    "load-image"
                ]
            }
        },
        "load-image-exif": {
            "path": "lib\/blueimp-load-image\/load-image-exif",
            "shim": {
                "deps": [
                    "load-image"
                ]
            }
        },
        "load-image-ios": {
            "path": "lib\/blueimp-load-image\/load-image-ios",
            "shim": {
                "deps": [
                    "load-image"
                ]
            }
        },
        "load-image-meta": {
            "path": "lib\/blueimp-load-image\/load-image-meta",
            "shim": {
                "deps": [
                    "load-image"
                ]
            }
        },
        "load-image-orientation": {
            "path": "lib\/blueimp-load-image\/load-image-orientation",
            "shim": {
                "deps": [
                    "load-image"
                ]
            }
        }
```

would be great if something like this worked:

```
        "load-image": {
            "path": "lib\/blueimp-load-image\/load-image",
            "shim": {
                "post-deps": [
                    "lib\/blueimp-load-image\/load-image-exif-map",
                    "lib\/blueimp-load-image\/load-image-exif",
                    "lib\/blueimp-load-image\/load-image-ios",
                    "lib\/blueimp-load-image\/load-image-meta",
                    "lib\/blueimp-load-image\/load-image-orientation"
                ]
            }
        }
```

See how much extra config has had to be done to accomplish this.

Why can't require just have something like a post-deps key that loads post path dependencies?

There are several libraries I have come across causing needing to be loaded in this fashion unnecessarily inflating my config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I want to call the libs I need to call all of the secondary libraries in my require() call instead of a single lib which I would like to avoid at all costs.

That's *sort of* the point of a library like require, it forces you to define all the dependencies of the script for a couple of reasons

- Ensures the lib is loaded *before* it's used by the dependant module
- Provides visibility over what libs a particular module *needs* to work

If I understand your problem correctly, you don't like the idea of having to do

```
require(['secondarylib1', 'secondarylib2', 'secondarylib3', ...], function(...) {
    ...
});
```

Whenever you want to load all the libs. Assuming each `secondarylib` requires `primarylib` then the simplest way to avoid this is to have a "*bootstrapper"* lib that loads all the dependant libraries for you e.g.

**Bootstrapper.js**

```
require(['secondarylib1', 'secondarylib2', 'secondarylib3', ...], function() {});
```

**Main.js**

```
require(['bootstrapper'], function() {
    // all libs would be loaded
    ...
});
```

Comment: I came to a similar conclusion and created a bootstrapper. Just feels like a lot of unnecessary config variables are being created inflating the size of my config file.

Comment: @DieterGribnitz that's the beauty of using require....you can modularize your config files!

Comment: thanks, never thought of that, will look into modularizing config files